# How to exit an Async function from another class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an `Async` method that does not end immediately after I close its user control. So, when I close and reopen it very fast, my user control gets errors.  How could I exit that `Async` function from another class. Is that possible?

```
Public Class Main       
    Private Sub mainfucn()
        'exit otherfunc
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Other
    Public Async Function otherfunc() As Task
        ' some code
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I honestly do not understand what it is you're trying to do... Could you add some more information about what you're actually trying to do? (Preferrably more than 7 words and a non-compiling code-snippet without any further explanations...)

Comment: What's calling the `otherfunc` method, in your example?  Is it executing on a different thread from the `mainfucn` [sic] method?

Comment: @bassfader you are right! .I edited the question so I hope is now cleared.

Comment: yes @StevenDoggart my real problem is this. I have an Async function that does not end immediately after I close its user control. So , when i close and reopen very fast my user control i get errors

Comment: So you want to cancel the `Async` method when the form closes?  Is the `Async` method your own (one that you can change, if need be), or is it one from the framework or some other library that you can't modify?  Also, does the `Async` method currently accept a `CancellationToken` argument?

Comment: Yes is my own async method. As for the second question I am not really sure , I tried to implement CancellationToken but without success.

Comment: The proper way to cancel an `async` function is to use a `CancelationToken` that you get from a `CancelationTokenSource`.  Anything with a reference to the `CancelationTokenSource` can request the cancelation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could slum it by implementing your own cancellation system yourself.  For instance, probably the simplest way to do something like that would be with some sort of cancellation flag property, like this:

```
Public Class Main       
    Private _other As New Other()

    Private Sub MainFunc()
        other.Cancelled = True
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Other
    Public Property Cancelled As Boolean    ' Yes, I know I'm not British, but the American spelling of "Canceled" is phonetically stupid.  But, then again, so is the spelling of "British", so...

    Public Async Function OtherFunc() As Task
        Cancelled = False
        While Not Cancelled
            ' Some code
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, that would be pretty terrible, so I wouldn't recommend it.  The two primary reasons why it's terrible is because, *One*, it assumes that there's only ever one `Async` method and that there's only ever one invocation of it running at a time.  And *Two*, it is inconsistent with the standard async cancellation patterns of .NET.

I would strongly recommend that, instead of attempting to do it with your own (anti-) pattern, you should add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your `Async` function.  However, the way that you would implement that within the method all depends on what it is doing asynchronously and how it does it.  So it's impossible to give you a single good example for how to accomplish that.  The best thing I could say is, you were on the right track with using a `CancellationToken`, so you should keep going down that path.  If, after doing more research, you aren't able to get it working, then I would recommend posting a more specific question regarding how to implement a `CancellationToken` within the context of what your method is doing and how it operates.